# Laravel: Pegar o valor de um array sem precisar de foreach

Tags: php, array, laravel, laravel-5, back-end

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
$TenantId = DB::select('select tenant_id from users where id = :id', ['id' => '7']);

dd($TenantId);
```

O resultado de $TenantId é:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#357 ▼
    +"tenant_id": 7
  }
]
```

Preciso que o resultado seja apenas: 7

Como faço para exibir apenas o numero 7? O motivo é porque preciso deste 'tenant_id' para utilizar na consulta seguinte que é:

```
$subdomain = DB::select('select subdomain from tenants where id = :id', ['id' => $TenantId]);
```

Mas se eu utilizar desta forma acima exibe o erro:

***Array to string conversion (SQL: select subdomain from tenants where id = :id)***

Já tentei pegar o valor das seguintes formas, mas não resolveu:

***$TenantId['tenant_id'];***

ou

***$TenantId[0]['tenant_id'];***

ou

***extract($TenantId);***

*Todas as 3 formas deram erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que deu pra perceber o correto seria usar $TenantId[0]->tenant_id

Comment: Obrigado amigo...Esclarecido a dúvida...Realmente desta forma deu certo, aprendi mais uma, obrigado!